# Sobre poner un una palomita del check

Tags: html

Como obtener esto en HTML [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo puedo colocarla de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me serian de gran ayuda.

```
#Competencia input:checked + span  {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #850DFE;
    color: #33409A;
    border: 2px solid #850DFE;
    background: url(https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/blue/ok-xxl.png) right top no-repeat;        background-size: 14px 14px;
    background-origin: border-box;
    box-shadow: 1px 1.5px darkblue;
    background-origin: border-box;
      }
```

Comment: He intentado con z-Index y sin embargo no he logrado conseguirlo

Comment: para que zindex te funcione debe tener position absolute o relative o debe tener float aplicado. Deberiamos poder ver el html para responder con certeza